# How do I open the "Find Users, Contacts, and Groups" dialog without using Rundll32?

Tags: windows-7, windows, active-directory

There is a nice dialog that helps to search for Active Directory groups in Windows called `Find Users, Contacts, and Groups`.

Unfortunately, I only know how to open it with this command:

```bsh
Rundll32 dsquery.dll OpenQueryWindow
```

Is this dialog available from the Start Menu or Control Panel?  I cannot find it.

To clarify, I am regular user of Windows 7 Enterprise, and do not normally have local admin rights.

Sample screenshot:

[image: AD - Find Users, Contacts, and Groups]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch an Explorer window of a network server (Note that this may not work 100% on all operating system. The OS may need to be set as a file server for this to properly work.). The contextualized Explorer window will have amongst its taskbar hot buttons, adjacent to "Organize" pull-down menu, a "Search active directory" button. Click it - this launches Find Users, Contacts, and Groups - with  "Entire Directory" as the default search home location.

Additional info:
For non-server versions of windows you need to install [ADUC Tools](https://www.technipages.com/windows-install-active-directory-users-and-computers) in order for the "Search AD" option to appear:

Comment: I am not an expert with Windows.  Can you please be more specific about this instruction... ? "Launch an Explorer window of a network server"  Also, to clarify, I am regular user; not a network admin (or even local admin).

Comment: The option is only present in server versions of windows. To add it to the rest (like for W7), install the tools I added in the main reply.

Comment: I have changed the link to a working one, valid for all windows versions.

Answer (score 4):

If you want something clickable, you can create a .bat file with the following:

```
@echo off
start Rundll32 dsquery.dll OpenQueryWindow
```

Answer (score 2):

From a german `windows-explorer` in `windows-10`:

- Open the `windows-explorer`
- Click the **Network** menu
- On the network toolbar on top click **Search active directory**

[image]

Comment: You still required the *Active Directory Users and Computers* tools as mentioned by the accepted answer. While I wish the accepted answer was more detailed, and didn’t have a broken link, it still is correct.  Windows 10 doesn’t have the button you mentioned unless you install the tools.  Exception to that statement is you must be running 1809 (but the feature must be enabled)

Comment: I have never claimed the accepted answer as incorrect, rather than improving it by a visual screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Windows OS version : 8.1

> - Newtork and Internet -> Click on "View network computers and devices"
> - Top Menu bar view -> Search Active Directory
> - Find Users, Contacts and Groups popup would appear

You search for any user or group in this window and their access level to the folders.